# Can I construct or find out a new kind of field?

Tags: geometry, field-theory

I need to construct **any new type of Construct-able field** for my purpose of research purpose in geometry. But I have doubt whether it is easy to found or most tougher problem.

**Can I construct or find out a new kind of field** ?

**Answer:**

I am thinking that to construct a new type of any field surely difficult .

Can I manipulate a new kind of field from our well-known field $ \ \mathbb{R} \ \ and \ \ \mathbb{Q} \ $ by **imposing extra elements** or **extra elements** .

But I am getting no inspiration because I am thinking it will be in vain in advanced.

**Therefore I need your valuable hints or advice or answer.**

Help me with at least a little conclusion .

Comment: Yes it ok if it is Near a field or semi -field. However it would be better if it is a field.

Comment: What properties do you want this field to have?  In particular, why are the fields you know insufficient?  There are other fields.  One that might be useful is the field of constructable numbers.  It is a subset of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Sir I want to test the properties of Geometries over arbitrary fields. This is something I want to proceed. Actually I am searching some unsolved problems which are not so difficult in geometry (finite or infinite no matter) so that I can work on that.

Comment: Your question: "Can I manipulate a new kind of field from our well-known field $ \ \mathbb{R} \ \ and \ \ \mathbb{Q} \ $ by **imposing extra elements** or **extra elements** ."    This suggests that you are not looking what mathematicians would consider a "new kind" of field, but rather for what mathematicians already know as "field extensions".  This is a classical subject, and you can read about it in many books on abstract algebra.   Look for keywords:  fields, field extensions, Galois theory.

Comment: I don't know why all of you downvoted my question. I shared what I really feeling. please at least help the question ahead

Comment: Only two people downvoted the question, neither of them me.  You have not explained why you think you need a different field, nor what it should do for you.  Different geometries can be specified by having real or complex coordinates and defining a different metric.  Hyperbolic and spherical geometries work this way.  Without knowing what is wrong with the existing fields it is impossible to answer.

Comment: yourmath is right about the downvotes.  This is an example of a mathematically unsophisticated person (sorry, yourmath) trying to think in an adventurous way about mathematics.  He/she is unable to formulate things precisely because of lack of sophistication.  In my opinion such interest should either be encouraged or just ignored, if you don't want to engage helpfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a field, two important aspects: cardinality and characteristic.

Finite fields or Galois fields with symbol $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ are constructed and studied using quotients of polynomials and so on.

For fields with characteristic zero, with all of them contain $\mathbb{Q}$, we have some famous fields like $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}_p$ (p-adic numbers). These two fields are constructed using concept of metric and completion of rationals $\mathbb{Q}$ and there is only this two type of fields which can be constructed using "completion" method.

Also, field of complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$, skew field of quaternions, $\mathbb{H}$ and octonions $\mathbb{O}$ and so on, constructed using "Cayley-Dickson" method, which constructs $2^n$-dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-algebras over Cartesian product $\mathbb{R}\times\cdots\times\mathbb{R}$.

So if any of these method don't satisfy you, then you need to create your own method to constructing new fields.

Comment: There is also the field of real polynomials $\Bbb R[x]$

Comment: @RossMillikan: I think you mean field of rational functions which is fraction field of integral domain $\mathbb{R}[x]$. Yes, it is. Note also that We also have generalization of this field to field of Laurent series, Puiseux series and Hahn series.

Comment: A kind and helpful answer.

Comment: @RossMillikan That is not a field.